# Mongo query - push unique items and preserve order in array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

So this is a fairly common scenario where I want to add unique items and preserve order in an array - I have a collection of mongo docs that follow this schema:

```
{
   _id: ObjectID,
   name: string,
   email: string
   favorites: [array of objectIDs]
}
```

I'm trying to update the favorites array only if the ID I am trying to add doesn't already exist. I also need to PRESERVE ORDER in the array and hence only want to append at the end.

I'm getting a *"Cannot read property '_id' of null"* error with the following update command...what am I doing wrong?

```
Customer.findOneAndUpdate(
           {
                _id: customerId, //find correct customer doc
                favorites: {
                   $ne: itemId //only push if array doesn't already contain
                }
            },
            {
                $push: {
                    favorites: itemId
                }
            },
            { new: true} //return updated doc
)
```

I'm using $push to preserve order, and wanted to use the $ne operator to prevent duplicates in the customers favorites array. If I take out the favorites block it can find the doc but adds duplicates. As soon as I add in the favorites filter with the $ne, it complains with "Cannot read property '_id' of null".

Comment: Looks like `customerId` is null , can you console.log and check that.

Comment: hmm I dont think so - the filter section works fine if I take out the favorites filter and just do { _id: customerID }. I also logged it and it does indeed contain the correct ID

Comment: Try this one: `{_id: customerId, favorites: { $nin: [itemId] } }`

Answer (score 19):

Try `$addToSet` instead of `$push`.

$addToSet by default only adds to set if it is not present. For example...

```
{
    $addToSet: {
        favorites: itemId
    }
}
```

Source: https://database.guide/mongodb-push-vs-addtoset-whats-the-difference/